# how to reload value after clicking in vue

Tags: vue.js, loading

I'm trying to reload values when switching tab without reloading the page. I'm getting the value from a method.

```
mounted() {
  this.getOriginalSpace();
},
methods: {
  getOriginalSpace() {
    retrieveQuotaSummary(this.value.organisation, this.value.dataCenter)
      .then((result) => {
        this.quotaSummary = result;
      });
  }
}
```

after that, I read the needed value out of `quotaSummary` like this (computed):

```
previouslyYarnCPU() {
  return this.quotaSummary.currentAcceptedYarnRequest
    ? this.quotaSummary.currentAcceptedYarnRequest.cpu
    : 0;
},
```

Then, when I switch tab, and call an other function in computed mode, I still have the same value which was loaded above. But when I refresh the page, then I get the correct (new value).

Can someone please help me, how I can get the latest values without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Show the whole component code, please.

Comment: You simply need to call `getOriginalSpace` every time you need the new value. You might read about methods and computed properties in vue regarding computed properties caching behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult as I would need to see the rest of your code but in order to get values when they change you need to use a computed function. You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example)